# overriding super class member

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I am trying to inherit a class defined in a public library while overriding some of its functions and member types and I have a few questions:

1. None of the functions are declared as virtual in the super class so is it still ok to override these functions?
2. Can I override member variables by simply declaring a variable with the same name but a different type.  Is this the same as hiding?
3. Also, if 2 is possible, then can I do the following:

   ```
   public class A {
     public:
       class Member {
           Member (//some params) {};
       }
   }

   class B : public A {
     public:
       class Member : public A::Member {
           Member () :
              A::Member(//some params) 
           {
               // Some additions to B::Member
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Note: Since I cannot change the superclass templating is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you hide the base class's functions - you can't override them as they're not virtual - you have to keep in mind that certain scenarios like calling via pointer or reference to the base class will not work as expected and might yield "interesting" results. You'll also run into issues if the destructor is non-virtual and you're trying to destroy the derived object via a pointer to base class.
2. You'd be hiding the base class's member of the same name, but again it is very likely that it will not do what you expect. The base class implementation will still reference the base class's member, while the derived class's implementation will reference the derived class's member.
3. No.

You might want to look into wrapping the "base" class instead of trying to derive from it.

Answer (score 1):

1. you override virtual functions. if it is not, you are hiding.
2. it is name hiding.
3. no you can not.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you can't override them. It will be simply hiding them.
2. It's not overriding, it is hiding.
3. You can't.